# Read Date and Time from the Excel File using Selenium Webdriver c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to read the data from the Excel file but the method i am using is putting a ' (single quote) in front of the date in the excel sheet. What are the other ways of doing it

Comment: You can't read excel file with Selenium. Post your code, expected results and actual results.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can enter the date in excel without `'`, and change format the date once you read it from excel with in your script to the desired format. - just a side note you need libraries to read the excel data